# Non-programmatical way to keep a web-page down down menu active when changing Window focus to do a screenshot?

Tags: macos, screenshot, window-focus

I am trying to screen shot a web page of a site that I am working on.

Is there an non programming way (for quickness) to force the browser to keep menus open when the focus of the Window changes from the browser to the screenshot making app (using this on a Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grab utility (included in OS X) can do timed captures - start the timer, and you have 10 seconds to get everything arranged before it takes the shot. BTW, Grab also lets you control whether the mouse pointer is included in the shot (and what it looks like).

Comment: +1 That's an even better solution than mine - thank you. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Command key + Shift + 3 seems to work and not affect the visual state of the menu. Command key + Shift + 3 does the screenshot and places it as a file Screen Shot (with date) on the Desktop.

So I don't need that app to do the screenshot :)